# Memory allocation for structure extension

Tags: c

Suppose I have two structures one of which extends the other one (as below). What's the correct procedure for dealing with memory when creating an extended structure from an existing structure? Should malloc be called again for the new structure? Would this be doubling up memory allocation where it shouldn't be?

```
typedef struct Grid {
  int rows;
  int cols;
  int * grid;
} Grid;

typedef struct SuperGrid { 
    Grid; 
    char * property;
    int id;
} SuperGrid;

static Grid * new_grid(int rows, int cols) {
  Grid * grid = (Grid *)(malloc(sizeof(Grid))); 
  grid->rows= rows;
  grid->cols= cols;
  grid->grid = (int *)(calloc(rows*cols, sizeof(int)));
}

static SuperGrid * new_super_grid(int rows, int cols) {
    /* What needs to happen here? */
    return (SuperGrid *)new_grid(rows, cols); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *structure extension* mechanism is similar to a primitive C++ class derivation system.
To achieve your goal, you need to separate structure allocation and initialization:

```
typedef struct Grid {
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int *grid;
} Grid;

typedef struct SuperGrid { 
    Grid; 
    char *property;
    int id;
} SuperGrid;

static Grid *init_grid(Grid *grid, int rows, int cols) {
    if (grid) {
        grid->rows = rows;
        grid->cols = cols;
        grid->grid = (int *)calloc(rows * cols, sizeof(int));
    }
    return grid;
}

static Grid *new_grid(int rows, int cols) {
    return init_grid((Grid *)malloc(sizeof(Grid)), rows, cols);
}

static SuperGrid *init_super_grid(SuperGrid *sg, int rows, int cols,
                                  const char *property, int id) {
    if (sg) {
        init_grid((Grid *)sg, rows, cols);
        sg->property = strdup(property);
        sg->id = id;
    }
    return sg;
}

static SuperGrid *new_super_grid(SuperGrid *sg, int rows, int cols,
                                 const char *property, int id) {
    return init_super_grid((SuperGrid *)malloc(sizeof(SuperGrid)),
                           rows, cols, property, id);
}
```

The allocators may fail and will return `NULL` in case of memory allocation failure.  You may want them to fail in more explicit ways such as exiting the program with an error message via `abort`.  Similarly, the `delete_xxx` functions should gracefully ignore `NULL` pointers as `free` does and the C++ `delete` operator.

For consistency, you will also separate the `delete_grid` and `finalize_grid` functions in order to call the `finalize_grid` from `finalize_super_grid`.  It is not strictly necessary for this simple example, but may prove handy if you instantiate `Grid` structures that are not allocated (with static or automatic storage or embedded in more complex superstructures).

This poor man's C++ class system will quickly show its limitations.  You may consider using C++ directly.

Comment: @Nisse Engström: thanks for pointing this mistake.  I was wondering if the `init_xxx` functions should take a `void *` argument to get rid of all the casts.  Of course the casts on `malloc` and `calloc` return values are not needed but may help prevent allocating the wrong size.

Comment: There's a somewhat cavalier disregard for the possibility of an allocation function returning a null pointer.  That's probably not a good idea in production code.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: I agree. There are 2 options: let the `new_xxx` functions return the `NULL` pointer and hope the caller will deal with memory allocation failure or `abort` with an error message.